# 12.04 rebooting after suspend to disk

Tags: 12.04, suspend, hibernate

I've got a problem with suspend to disk in ubuntu 12.04 (it worked perfectly in 11.10).
I've installed the `pm-utils` package, but whenever I issue:

`sudo pm-hibernate`

it appears the screen that notifies me that the s2disk image is being created (and it is), the system powers down, and then it powers up again, taking me back to where I was...

What can I do to prevent the system from rebooting?

I've tried to modify many options in the bios (S1, S3, no reboot after failure etc)

thanks

Comment: I'm kind of confused about the sentence "the system powers down, and then it powers up again, taking me back to where I was". It sounds like (to me) the process works if it took you back to where you were before the hibernate. Read this article to understand the hibernation process: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/hardware/C/pm-suspending.html

Comment: Omg, I meant that the hibernation works, but instead of shutting down, it reboots....

Comment: That still doesn't sound like a reboot to me.

Comment: I think he means the machine hibernates and power cycles right away, not staying powered off.

Comment: I understand that he doesn't want the system to restart immediately, without interaction, like hitting blank or moving the mouse. The system goes down and straight up again, instead of waiting to wake up.

Comment: @gianni when poking around a bit more with `pm-hibernate`, I noticed it happened to me as well (Did the command from above, looked like it went right into hibernation, started right back up). Poked around the launchpad,net site and didn't see anything yet but will also if I can gather more information as to why its happening this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I solved with:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure uswsusp
```

ShutdownMethod:

- reboot
- platform
- shutdown (choose this)

I also added (not sure if it is necessary, anyway it solved the watchdog problem):
"blacklist mei" to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Updating the bios, removing all usb devices and hubs, didn't help.
Now I have the problem that I doesn't lock the screen after resume....

Comment: awesome that you solved it. sorry for the confusion on my part. just wanted to make sure everyone (including myself) understood the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

I still have this problem with hibernation on my Dell XPS 13 with 12.04 installed.

Even after setting the dpkg command to shutdown as above, on giving the "s2disk" command, my machine saves the snapshot to disk and then comes back to the grub screen. Pressing the hardware switch switches off the machine immediately. The resume works correctly the next time it is switched on.

This is a pain, but it's better than not being able to hibernate at all...(which was the case until a few days back!)

Comment: Did anyone file this as a bug-report? if not see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug